# How do I make Navmesh Agent in Unity follow the closest player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, navmesh

I am making a multiplayer game where a navmesh agent follows the player, if there are multiple it only follows one until it is no longer in the scene. How would I make the Navmesh follow both?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
> {
> \[SerializeField\] private Transform movePositionTransform;

private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;

Start is called before the first frame update
private void Awake()
>     {
navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
>     }

Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
>     {
navMeshAgent.destination = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform.position;
>     }

> }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the agent to follow the closest player, check the distance between the players and the agent and choose the closest one to be set as the destination. I wouldn't use the `FindWithTag("Player")` method because it's really heavy (it iterates over all of the objects in the scene each step). Instead, I will create a list of the players and populate it on `Start()`, and then create another method for the agent that checks which player is the closest and sets him as the destination. Here is a psuedo code of what I mean:

```
List<Player> players;

void Start(){
    players = FindObjectsWithTag("Player")
}

void SetAgentDestination(){
    float min = 0;
    Player closest = null;
    foreach (Player p in players){
        if (<calculate distance> < min){
            min = <calculated distance>
            closest = p;
        }
    }
    agent.SetDestination(closest);
}
```

Something like this

Answer (score 0):

The [FindGameObjectsWithTag()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) method searches all object in your scene (one by one) to check if it meets the requirements (e.g: if it has the tag "Player")

Calling [FindGameObjectsWithTag()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) on [Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) makes it a poor performance code. Update is called once per frame. You're looping/searching through all objects at all possible times.

**Here's what you can do instead:**

You can use the [FindGameObjectsWithTag()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) on [Awake()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) or on [Start()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) instead, and cache/save it into a list or array. This way you only searching the objects once.

Check which player is the closest one ([Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)), and move the navmesh agent to it.

It should look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] List<GameObject> players;
    [SerializeField] Transform movePositionTransform;

    private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;

    //Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        players = FindObjectsWithTag("Player");
    }

    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        navMeshAgent.destination = GetClosestPlayer().transform.position;
    }

    //Loops through all players and returns the closest one
    GameObject GetClosestPlayer()
    {
        GameObject closestPlayer = players[0]; //settings the first player to be the closest one by default
        float distanceToClosestPlayer = Vector3.Distance(navMeshAgent.gameObject.transform.position, closestPlayer.transform.position);
        
        // loops/searches through all players
        foreach(GameObject player in players)
        {
            // calculate distance to this player
            float distanceToThisPlayer = Vector3.Distance(navMeshAgent.gameObject.transform.position, player.transform.position;

            // if this player is the closest one so far
            if (distanceToThisPlayer < distanceToClosestPlayer)
                {
                    // cache/save it
                    closestPlayer = player;
                    distanceToClosestPlayer = distanceToThisPlayer;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This caches the player once, on the Awake of the object. If the player list can change runtime after that (players can join/quit mid game) you should then be updating the current player list (maybe using delegates).